# Should I build separate tables for my product? Why not?

Tags: database-design

I'm building a website that offer four services (products), **in the near future each service (product) going to have its own website with its own database**, each service (product) totally has different data ( they only share the column "name")

And in the future, I won't have any other services (products) .

So I have built two prototypes, one that follows all the database designing rule that I know

The second is more convenient for when the database is separated

Which one is the right way? and is it bad to separate the (Order tables)? and why?

[image: Simple prototype 1]

[image: Simple prototype 2]

Comment: Having each product in it's own table feels wrong, but without knowing how each product differs from each other only you know if that makes sense. "Normally" you would just have _Products -> Orderlines -> Order_ and you add/remove product rows as needed.

Comment: If the table definitions are the same for `Product1...Product4`, then don't split them up. In the future you could have 2000 products, will you have 2000 tables to maintain?

Comment: Thank you for answering, each service (product) totally has different data ( they only share the column "name"), And in the future, I won't have any other services (products) .